# Edit the Top Visitor Site Web Analytics Report / Custom Application Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, application-pages, web-analytics

Currently the Top Visitors Report in the Site Web Analytics returns Visitors, Page Views, and Percentage. My issue is with the way it displays Visitors. It uses the Display name and since we have some users with the same first and last name we can't tell who is who. Is there a way to add the username or email in addition to or instead of the standard Visitor column?

I cannot seem to find good documentation on an API that would allow me to get the data otherwise I would just write a application page myself. Is that the better way to go to accomplish this?

I also looked at the Web Analytics Web Part but I was unable to see a way for it to help. Though I may have missed something as I have never worked on this part of SharePoint before.